# How to create a name based unique id as a number

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate database ids for my current project. we are currently using an approach similar to instagram (see: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram) so i need to generate a name based unique number (either based on the MAC or, preferably, the machine hostname).

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: What is your db?  If Oracle and all you want to do is "place the data in many smaller buckets, each holding a part of the data" then just partition the table.  If your goal is to meet the 3 listed features, then more work will be required.

Comment: i'm using mysql and need to partition over multiple servers, so partitioning the table on the db side does not help. i might assign the shard id to the database and fix the problem this way.